# What is type of Yii's relations in AR models

Tags: php, model, yii

I believe relations in AR models of Yii is returned as **Array**. But the book "Web Application Development with Yii and PHP" try use theme as **Object** instances and it makes error.
Am I missing something or understanding wrong Or it's book's mistake?

for example in 'Comment' AR model class we have:

```
public function relations()
{

    return array(
        'author' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'create_user_id'),
    );
}
```

book  refers to "username" as :

```
$comment->author->username
```

and I use :

```
$comment->author['username']
```

which one is correct?

UPDATE->
I'm gonna put all related code here:
**AR model:**

```
/**
 * This is the model class for table "tbl_comment".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'tbl_comment':
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $content
 * @property integer $issue_id
 * @property string $create_time
 * @property integer $create_user_id
 * @property string $update_time
 * @property integer $update_user_id
 *
 * The followings are the available model relations:
 * @property User $updateUser
 * @property Issue $issue
 * @property User $createUser
 */
class Comment extends TrackStarActiveRecord
{
/**book
 */
public function recent($limit=5)
{
    $this->getDbCriteria()->mergeWith(array(
    'order'=>'t.create_time DESC',
    'limit'=>$limit,)
    );
    return $this;   
}
/**
 * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
 * @param string $className active record class name.
 * @return Comment the static model class
 */
public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
{
    return parent::model($className);
}

/**
 * @return string the associated database table name
 */
public function tableName()
{
    return 'tbl_comment';
}

/**
 * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
 */
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('content, issue_id', 'required'),
        array('issue_id, create_user_id, update_user_id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('create_time, update_time', 'safe'),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('id, content, issue_id, create_time, create_user_id, update_time, update_user_id', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}

/**
 * @return array relational rules.
 */
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'updateUser' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'update_user_id'),
        'issue' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Issue', 'issue_id'),
        'author' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'create_user_id'),
    );
}

/**
 * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
        'id' => 'ID',
        'content' => 'Content',
        'issue_id' => 'Issue',
        'create_time' => 'Create Time',
        'create_user_id' => 'Create User',
        'update_time' => 'Update Time',
        'update_user_id' => 'Update User',
    );
}

/**
 * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
 * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
 */
public function search()
{
    // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
    // should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
    $criteria->compare('content',$this->content,true);
    $criteria->compare('issue_id',$this->issue_id);
    $criteria->compare('create_time',$this->create_time,true);
    $criteria->compare('create_user_id',$this->create_user_id);
    $criteria->compare('update_time',$this->update_time,true);
    $criteria->compare('update_user_id',$this->update_user_id);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
  }
  }
```

**Widget component:**

```
<?php
/**
* RecentCommentsWidget is a Yii widget used to display a list of
recent comments
*/
class RecentCommentsWidget extends CWidget
{
private $_comments;
public $displayLimit = 5;
public $projectId = null;
public function init()
{
    if(null !== $this->projectId)
        $this->_comments = Comment::model()-          >with(array('issue'=>array('condition'=>'project_id='.$this->projectId)))->recent($this->displayLimit)->findAll();
    else
        $this->_comments = Comment::model()->recent($this->displayLimit)->findAll();
}
public function getData()
{
return $this->_comments;
}
public function run()
{
// this method is called by CController::endWidget()
$this->render('recentCommentsWidget');
}
}
```

**widget view:**

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach($this->getData() as $comment): ?>
<div class="author">
    <?php echo $comment->author->username; ?> added a comment.
</div>
<div class="issue">
    <?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($comment->issue->name),
    array('issue/view', 'id'=>$comment->issue->id)); ?>
</div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

This code makes non-object error but when I change

```
$comment->author->username
```

to 
    $comment->author['username'] 
it works fine. I wonder how it's work for $issue by object access method.

Comment: If you have defined `public $author;` anywhere in the `Comment` model or its parents, that could explain the issue, especially if you somehow fill out that property with array data in some manner. The actual property existing will override Yii's magic getter for the relation.

Answer (score 0):

Both of those access methods will work. `CActiveRecord` instances use PHPs `ArrayAccess` class to provide array style access to it's attributes.

You might be referring to a relations type though:

`HAS_ONE` & `BELONGS_TO` both return a single object you can use directly as you gave as an example. These will also return `NULL` if no row is found.

`HAS_MANY` & `MANY_MANY` relations return an array, which you use like: `$model->authors[0]->name` or `$model->authors[1]->name`. These will return and empty `Array` if no rows are found.

`STAT` relations are a little different again, and return a single scalar value (integer, string, boolean etc.). Returns `0` on not found, but this can be configured through `defaultValue`

Read here for more:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr

Comment: But when I use it as object instance($comment->author->username) get this error:
'Trying to get property of non-object'
It means 'author' is not an object ,isn't it?

Comment: It will return NULL if no row is found, which is often where this error comes from. e.g. `$comment->NULL->username` = error

Comment: I think it's not NULL because ($comment->author['username']) works fine.

Comment: OK something strange must be going on with your setup or code then. Could you update your question with the code you're using to test this? That relation should only ever return an object or NULL as defined in your question.

Comment: I added code. It's long and I won't be upset if you don't have time for it.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended form is:

```
$comment->author->username
```

You can use the code below...

```
$comment->author['username']
```

...because the PHP handles the object as array.

Comment: but first method doesn't work and second method works fine , How ?

Comment: @secretarmy: Because... In Yii, you need use so: $comment->author->attributes['username']

Comment: Sorry, but that's just not true. The ActiveRecord models implement `ArrayAccess` for their attributes.

Comment: @Paystey I know, but... The proprety "author" is one relation of type "BELONGS_TO", and the class CBelongsToRelation not implement ArrayAccess.

Comment: You can do $model['propretyName'], but no can't do $model->relation['propretyName']

Comment: When u request the relation it doesn't return an instance of the relation type object. The actual returns are in my answer.